# jQuery plugin not firing correction keydown or idle events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I am programming a jQuery plugin which tracks specific events. I have provided 2 JSFiddle examples for the sanitised code to assist at the end of the question.

I am struggling to fathom why 2 particular events are not firing. The first function tracks when the user triggers the <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> keys within an `input` or `textarea` field. The code for this:

```
// Keydown events
$this.keydown(function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    // Tab key
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
        alert('tab key');
    } else if (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46) { // Backspace and Delete keys
        if ($this.val() !== '') {
            alert('Backspace or delete key');
        }
    }
});
```

I only wish to track the error-correction keys when a field is not empty. The <kbd>tab</kbd> key in the above example works as expected within the conditional statement. The <kbd>backspace</kbd> and <kbd>delete</kbd> keys do not work when inside the plugin and targeting the element in focus.

---

The second event not firing is tracking whether a user becomes idle. It is making use of [jQuery idle timer plugin](https://github.com/mikesherov/jquery-idletimer/blob/master/src/idle-timer.js) to manipulate the element in focus.

```
// Idle event
$this.focus(function() {
    $this.idleTimer(3000).bind('idle.idleTimer', function() {
        alert('Gone idle');
    });
}).focusout(function() {
    $this.idleTimer('destroy');
});
```

With both of these events I have refactored the code. They were outside of the plugin and targeted `$('input, select, textarea')` and worked as expected. I have brought them inside the plugin, and set them to `$(this)` to manipulate elements currently in focus. For most of the functions, this has worked without fault, but these 2 are proving problematic.

---

The first JSFiddle is with the 2 functions inside the plugin. <kbd>tab</kbd> works, whereas the correction keys do not. Strangely, in this example the idle function is firing (it does not in my dev environment). As this is working in the JSFiddle, I accept this may be difficult to resolve. Perhaps suggestions on handling an external plugin within my own to remedy this?

[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/digikev/aSys2/)

The second JSFiddle has taken the <kbd>backspace</kbd> and <kbd>delete</kbd> key functionality outside of the plugin and targets `$('input, select, textarea')` and now works.

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/digikev/sDmVf/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Fiddle1:

```
if ($this.val() !== '') {
        alert('Backspace or delete key');
}
```

Look at what `$this` actually is.

Comment: My hope was that `$this` would be the current element in focus. It appears I have this skewed? How would I pass the current element in focus to this function then?

Comment: Oh, don't mind my previous (deleted) comment. What about just this `$('input, select, textarea').contextHelp('browser');` instead of `$(document).contextHelp('browser');`. That means applying the plugin on all the editable elements instead of on document